# User-provided constructor vs explicitly defaulted one

Tags: c++, class, constructor

`N4296::12.8/11 [class.copy]` told us the following:

> A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class X is defined as deleted
>   (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> [...]
>
> (11.2) — a potentially constructed subobject type M (or array thereof)
>   that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as
>   applied to M’s corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a
>   function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted
>   constructor
>
> [...]

So it's not clear why the program

```
struct X
{
};

struct Y
{
    X&& x; 
    Y(Y const&)= default;
};

int main() { }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee822562dae5a533)**

works fine, but the following:

```
struct X
{
};

struct Y
{
    X&& x; 
    Y(Y const&);
};

Y::Y(Y const&)= default; //error

int main() { }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33f82b828245e0ad)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dcl.fct.def.default]/p5, emphasis mine:

> A function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not
>   explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. A
>   user-provided explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly
>   defaulted after its first declaration) is defined at the point where
>   it is explicitly defaulted; **if such a function is implicitly defined
>   as deleted, the program is ill-formed**.

This makes sense as any use of a deleted function should render a program ill-formed, but with a user-provided explicitly-defaulted function, it may be impossible to diagnose this at the call site:

```
// y.h
struct X
{
};

struct Y
{
    X&& x; 
    Y(Y const&);
};

// y.cpp
#include "y.h"
Y::Y(Y const&)= default; //defined as deleted

// main.cpp
#include "y.h"

int main() {
   Y y = Y();
}
```

When compiling `main.cpp`, the compiler has no idea about `Y`'s copy constructor other than that it exists; it doesn't know that it's defaulted, and can't possibly diagnose that it is actually deleted. The only place such a error can be diagnosed is where the function is explicitly defaulted.

Comment: Is it true that the program, containing a deleted constructor (in my case it was the copy constructor) will be ill-formed _iff_ the constructor is odr-used?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Which program? A program is ill-formed if a deleted function is referred to, other than to declare it.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c5a63feacd2f340) , for instance. In the program the copy constructor is odr-used, if I can say so. I meant whether the rule about usage of the deleted constructors has something to do with the odr-used concept. For example, if the deleted constructor is odr-used, the program is ill-formed or something similar.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Any use is sufficient, including in an unevaluated operand; odr-use is not required.